# Connect to hive with sqlalchemy odbc.ini file

Tags: python-3.x, hive, sqlalchemy, odbc

I'd like to connect to Hive using sqlalchemy and odbc.ini file

I have a odbc.ini file that looks like

```
[Hive]
Description = ODBC Hive connection to Hadoop cluster
Driver = /opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/64/libclouderahiveodbc64.so
HOST = host1,host2,host3
Schema = default
ServiceDiscoveryMode = 1
ZKNamespace = hiveserver2
HiveServerType = 2
AuthMech = 1
ThriftTransport = 1
UseNativeQuery = 0
KrbHostFQDN = _HOST
KrbServiceName = hive
ServicePrincipalCanonicalization = 1
SSL = 0
TwoWaySSL = 0
```

I tried to connect with

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

query_test = """SELECT * FROM my_table limit 1;"""

engine =  sqlalchemy.create_engine("hive://@Hive")
conn = engine.connect()
print(pd.read_sql(query_test, conn))
```

which produces the error
TTransportException: failed to resolve sockaddr for Hive:10000

in

```
~/folder/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py in open(self)
    125             msg = 'failed to resolve sockaddr for ' + str(self._address)
    126             logger.exception(msg)
--> 127             raise TTransportException(type=TTransportException.NOT_OPEN, message=msg,         inner=gai)
    128         for family, socktype, _, _, sockaddr in addrs:
    129             handle = self._do_open(family, socktype)
```

I've been told that this is because we have multiple host and have to go by something called zookeeper

What I cant understand is that when I use pyodbc there is no problem. The following works just fine

```
pyodbc.autocommit = True
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(dsn='Hive', autocommit=True)
data = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn, params=params)
cnxn.close()
```

How should I configure my sqlalchemy code to work with my odbc.ini file?

I have

```
PyHive-0.6.5
thrift-0.16.0
thrift_sasl-0.4.3
SQLAlchemy-1.4.36
sasl-0.3.1
pyodbc-4.0.32
```

Comment: Are you using [PyHive](https://pypi.org/project/PyHive/)? If so, it does not appear to use odbc.

Comment: Yes I'm under the impression that sqlalchemy uses pyhive under the hood when having create_engine("hive://@") @GordThompson

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to use the Hive ODBC Connector from Cloudera to connect to Hive, but then you use a `hive://` URI, which mean SQLAlchemy is going to try to use pyHive, which is unaware of `odbc.ini`.

To connect through ODBC from SQLAlchemy you need to use a `<dialect>+pyodbc://` URI, such as [`mssql+pyodbc://`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#dialect-mssql-pyodbc-connect), [`mysql+pyodbc://`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#dialect-mysql-pyodbc-connect) or [`sybase+pyodbc://`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sybase.html#dialect-sybase-pyodbc-connect).

There is no equivalent dialect for Hive + ODBC, so even if you manage a Hive connection through pyODBC in SQLAlchemy, it would not know how to speak to Hive. I found this repo [AurelienGalicher/PyHiveODBC](https://github.com/AurelienGalicher/PyHiveODBC) which seems to contain a [first draft](https://github.com/AurelienGalicher/PyHiveODBC/blob/master/pyhiveodbc/sqlalchemy_hiveodbc.py) of a Hive + ODBC dialect, but I have not tested it.

The pyHive documentation points to [connecting SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive#sqlalchemy) directly through a `hive://` URI.

So either you need to develop a Hive + ODBC dialect, or use pyHive, which does not use ODBC at all (and therefore no odbc.ini DSN).